# Struts 2.5.10.1 Migration <s:text> not working

Tags: struts2

I have migrated Struts 2.3 to 2.5.10.1.

```
<s:div name='#rep-<s:text name=#rep[0]>'></s:div>
```

working fine in struts2.0 but in 2.5 i have to write

```
<s:div name='#rep-<s:property name=#rep[0]>'></s:div>
```

I have read the migration guide and followed it. Problem is `<s:text>` not working properly even there is no exception. Any idea ?

Comment: Could you share more information? JSP snippet, globalmessages and output?

Comment: @mmalmeida:  <s:div name='#rep-<s:text name=#rep[0]>'></s:div>. working fine in struts2.0 but in 2.5 i have to write <s:div name='#rep-<s:property name=#rep[0]>'></s:div>.

Comment: First of all neither of them would work in 2.3. Read migration guide again.

Comment: @AleksandrM: Its working in 2.3

Comment: Do you know what `<s:text>` is for? And no, it doesn't work in 2.3. And read again migration guide.

Comment: `<s:text>` is NOT for input purposes.